# Do I need unicode to identify different writing system

Tags: unicode, go

Whether it is optimal or not, I am trying to identify specific characters using its hexadecimal code. (Is there better way to identify alphabets, Arabic, Chinese, or Japanese characters?)

http://play.golang.org/p/b81_rgXr3G

```
   fmt.Printf("%x \n", "가") //eab080
   fmt.Printf("%x \n", "ㅎ") //e3858e
```

So it is true that in Korean
eab080 < e3858e

Then my question is 
do we have any table or chart for each language's hexadecimal boundary?

I mean, for English

```
 fmt.Printf("%x \n", "A") //41
 fmt.Printf("%x \n", "z") //7a
```

Then 41 < 7a

As you see above, the alphabet is to be bounded between 41 and 7a.
I am trying out the same thing for another writing system that is not in alphabet.

Do I need unicode to identify different writing system? The unicode standard library seems only to provide encode and decode English alphabets.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: OT: I think it isn't called the English writing system, but the Latin "writing system". There are quite a few languages that use the same (and even more) letters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, we do not have any table or chart for each language’s hexadecimal boundary. There is some data about characters typically used in various languages.

This answers the question asked, but you should consider whether that was your real problem. The question refers to writing systems, alphabets, and languages as if they were one thing; they are separate concepts. You should define your practical problem: what information do you *really* need? In a text in some language, *any* Unicode character may appear.

By the way, English has (at least in some forms of the language) also words like fiancé, coöoperation, rôle, anæmia, belovèd, etc.

Comment: Thanks, mainly to identify Chinese and Korean characters that does not have alphabet letters. Guess I should brute-force to find the boundary?